# Stub a class method on an OCMPartialMock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method, ocmock

I’m using OCMock, and attempting to test a class with two class methods. I’d like to stub one in order to write a test for the other, so I’d normally use an `OCMPartialMock`. However, if I do this, I can’t call the class method since `OCMPartialMock` uses an instance of the class, not the class itself. If I use `OCMClassMock`, it’ll lose the implementation of the method I want to test.

In summary: I have two class methods, and I’d like to stub one but retain the ability to call the other, using OCMock. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: need to use an `OCMClassMock`, and since it’s swizzled the class, call the other class method on the class itself, not on my mocked `id` version.

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

+ (void)hello;//this is a class method

@end



id mock = OCMClassMock([MyModel class]);

[OCMStub([mock hello]) andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
      NSLog(@"hello everyone"); 
 }];

[MyModel hello];    //it will print  'hello everyone'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).